# Suppress "mixed spaces and tabs" warning in JSHint / JSLint or alternative service?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

JSHint and JSLint are awesome tools.

However, the "mixed spaces and tabs" warning dominates the report. Is there a way to suppress these warnings, or is there a similar service that allows white space warnings to get suppressed?

Comment: i solved it ultimately by writing a simple JS script to adjust white space in the code before pasting it into jshint.

Comment: There is a trick, remove all the white space(\t,\n,\0, spaces). rebuild it. It should work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
/*jshint smarttabs:true */
```

See `smarttabs`, under "Relaxing Options." http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/

> This option suppresses warnings about mixed tabs and spaces when the latter are used for alignmnent only. The technique is called [SmartTabs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs).

Comment: you are way too awesome. but you and your 78.3K points already knew that.

Comment: Hmm, weird, we pasted this at the top of the script block, and it's still showing the warning ... is there something else we need to do?

Comment: Hm - I had an extra space between `/*` and `jshint`; that might be the cause. Edited.

Comment: Nope, we just tried that, too (saw it from reading the docs). We're supposed to just put this line at the top of the code block right? Nothing else?

Comment: Yup. It depends on how you're actually using spaces. If the code's white space is simply sloppy, and _not_ just using spaces for aligment only, this option won't help you.

Comment: Yes, **iff** there is an error. For example: http://www.jshint.com/reports/409010

Comment: I see smarttabs:true up top in this report... anyway, we'll try to work through this. Probably something stupid on our end.

Comment: Are there alternative services for JS validation since SmartTabs was not the solution? We still see the "mixed tabs and spaces" warning even with SmartTabs set to true.

Comment: I think JSLint's "Tolerate messy white space" option will work for you. You're going to get some much more opinionated warnings/errors from JSLint, however.

Comment: i solved it ultimately by writing a simple JS script to adjust white space in the code before pasting it into jshint. thanks!

Comment: The `smarttabs` option has been removed from jshint: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/4035fef1af4ef426e9dc99918ca3aac0ce44b784

Answer (score 59):

It's not possible to switch off this warning with a flag, and the [JSHint maintainer doesn't want to add a flag for this](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/669#issuecomment-9407095).

However, it is possible to turn off warnings according to [their number](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/e3df309b2a84ca627d5fe85e60c296b6735d4b66/src/shared/messages.js). In this case, you'd write:

```
/* jshint -W099 */
```

If you're using a JSHint configuration file, you can specify this there too:

```
{
    "-W099": true, // allowed mixed tabs and spaces
}
```

Alternatively, there's a [custom reporter available](https://gist.github.com/valueof/3885619) to switch off this warning.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for actually answering the question!

Comment: I'd like to use this option in eclipse's JSHint plugin but when I paste `"-W099": true` in the plugin options box it does not work (a build error is shown saying "missing : after property id"). Tried without quotes and then it says "Bad option: -W099". Do you have any idea how should I configure this?

Comment: @MisterSmith this is a relatively new JSHint feature, are you using a recent version?

Comment: I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse). According to the docs, it uses JSHint r12.

Comment: r12 is eight months old, and doesn't include this.

Answer (score 5):

**Answer for 2014: upgrade jshint** As @RobW mentioned earlier, jshint [no longer complains about mixed spaces and tabs](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/4035fef1af4ef426e9dc99918ca3aac0ce44b784).  I have tested this by upgrading to jshint@2.5.10 and re-linting my document, which no longer complains (I consistently indent using tabs, but commenting out lines in SublimeText triggered this warning).

```
sudo npm update -g jshint
```

Comment: I have the latest and it does complain